# How can I organize my content using hierarchical taxonomy?

Tags: taxonomy-terms

My question is rather simple, but I don't know how to do it ?

I want to display a content with various fields, but I want the user to browse "hierarchically". For instance :

- Choose brand : BMW
- Choose model : BMW / Z3
- Choose specific model : BMW / Z3 / 2.0 i

I already made a taxonomy "Brand", a taxonomy "Model", I have a view that shows all brands.

What can I do ?

Thanks for advice, it would help me a lot !

Comment: Have you tried any of the following modules? [Hierarchical select](https://www.drupal.org/project/hierarchical_select) or [Simple hierarchical select](https://www.drupal.org/project/shs). The latter has a Views filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar implementation on a drupal 6 site using [Hierarchical Select](https://www.drupal.org/project/hierarchical_select). The drupal 7 branch turned out to be working slightly differently when I first tried to make the move.

There is also [Simple hierarchical select](https://www.drupal.org/project/shs) which was probably developed because of these 'differences' between d6 and d7:

> "This module has been inspired by Hierarchical select but is much simpler (…)."

I haven't tried *'Simple hierarchical select'* yet, but if I would re-build that d6 site again, I would probably go for *'Simple hierarchical select'*.

Both let you generate a taxonomy tree with dependend parent-child-relationships. So instead of having one taxonomy `brand`and one one taxonomy `model` you would have a taxonomy tree taht would contain all the branches down to `specific model`.

In my case is was `venues` which then also contained the upper branches like `city`and `country`.

PS: You could however also use entity references to build complex hierarchical content trees. You would then for example have a content type `brand` and a content type `model` referencing each other.  Nowadays I find this approach more convenient than dealing with taxonomy trees – but that's of course depending on personal preferences and/or content structure.

Comment: I tried the module - so if I am understanding well, I will have to use sub-terms in the taxonomy ? For instance, the taxonomy I named "Brand" will also contain the "model types" and the "models" ?

Comment: yes – afaik using one of the above modules you would only have one taxonomy tree.

Comment: That sounds a bit 'dramatic' – good luck! Btw: you can also build rich content trees *without* using texonomy trees – I updated my answer accordingly…

Comment: That's where I am lost : can you help me a bit more ? Do you have an example I can check of entity references ? Because my taxonomy is going to be VERY HUGE and if something more convenient than taxonomy is usable, I'll give it a try - I just didn't know anything else existed :) Thanks a lot for your help !

Comment: It really depends on your content structure and your workflow. If you prefer to present rather large, 'ready-made' taxonomy trees to your editors, then taxonomy is probably the way to go. If you instead like adding new child nodes 'on the fly' then entity reference can be an alternative. This article http://www.digett.com/blog/04/04/2012/rip-taxonomy-module-drupal-7 made me think – while some of if may be very true, other paragraphs are a bit 'over the top'. But still it can be a good starting point to re-think the idea of 'content trees' instead of 'taxonomy trees'.

Comment: In fact, this was EXACTLY what I aimed to do, I watched this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AcVz8Thxq48 to have a glimpse, and I won't use taxonomy anymore for my website. Thanks a lot !

Comment: Just one additional thought: the *entity reference* approach can however become a bit 'clumbsy'. Currently working on a website with hundreds of cross-referencable nodes, the 'free tagging' field "entityreference_prepopulate" becomes a bit slow or cluttered. Thinking about adding the 'entity reference view' module to solve this… But still wouldn't trade the current setup for taxonomies.

Comment: Yes, I understand what you mean - but with +1000 references in the website, it comes very handy : I managed to do whatever I wanted ; if I want to organize things differently, I'll only have to make a new content type and that's done.

Thanks for solving a big problem that I had :D